# recording cross-buffer cut-and-paste

Tags: logging

I'm interested in trying to track where my ideas come from.

Suppose I open files f1,f2,f3
and cut-and-paste lines from these files into f4.

I'd like to record this information in a log file (say f4.meta)

(at  copied data from f1 to f4)

Is there a way to do program this?

Also if I copy and paste text from outside emacs (say a browser)
is there some way to track and time stamp where the data came from?

Comment: Check out [Memacs](https://github.com/novoid/Memacs). It's not exactly what you are asking for, but does some sort of automatic tracking for you. Also, when copying from a browser, you can use org-protocol instead of the usual copy-paste to get meta information into an org-capture buffer. [Here's some info](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-protocol-capture-html#org-protocol-instructions).

Comment: You can advise the command(s) that you use for copying/killing text (or perhaps for yanking/pasting text, or both). The advice part would append the copied (or pasted) text to a log buffer/file, along with a timestamp or whatever other info you want.

Comment: `gui-get-selection` gives for text copies from firefox just the property `(foreign-selection STRING)`. Therefore I doubt that you get information about the source program of the selection within emacs. Logging copies from buffer to buffer should be feasible.